# post multiple field of file upload in different folder in node js api using multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I am using `multer` for single file upload in 1 `post field` but what if i want to add 2 or more file inside different `post field` like below.

this is for different module.

[image]

so for single file upload i am using following code

```
var uploadfilename = "";
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './public/assets' + customStrings.FOLDER)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    uploadfilename = Date.now() + 
    path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, uploadfilename);
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});
```

and in post api route

```
router.post("/news", upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {

});
```

now if i want multiple field for file upload what we will do ??

Answer (score 0):

i fount one solution for that is following

```
var uploadfilename = "";
var uploadCityfilename = "";
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.fieldname == "image") {
      cb(null, './public/assets' + customStrings.FOLDER)
    } else {
      cb(null, './public/assets' + customStrings.CITY_FOLDER)
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.fieldname == "image") {
      uploadfilename = Date.now() + "-" + 
      customStrings.IMAGE_POST_NAME + path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, uploadfilename);
    } else {
      uploadCityfilename = req.body.city + path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, uploadCityfilename);

    }
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});
```

and in post api route

```
router.post("/imageupload", upload.any(), (req, res) => {

});
```

it works for me :)